# Upper case between a char python

Tags: python, python-3.x, uppercase

I need help how do I get upper case between two stars like this.

INPUT: `"S*t*a*r*s are every*where*"`

OUTPUT: `"STaRs are everyWHERE"`

My code is here:

```
def trans(s):
    x = ""
    a = False
    for j in range(len(s)):
        if s[j] == "*" or a:
            a = True
            if a:
                x += s[j].upper()
        else:
            x += s[j]
    return "".join(x.replace("*",""))
```

The problem is I don't know where in loop set back to `False`. Now it just sees `*` and makes everything uppercase.

[image: state machine]

Comment: in stars, 't' and 'r' are also changed to capital letters??

Comment: @upaangsaxena: yes, because they follow directly after a star.

Comment: This is a very famous automaton. To understand the answers, do check this image http://s9.postimg.org/j9qyp60e7/auto.png

Comment: @BhargavRao: I've added your picture inline.

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian Tnx you, now I understand it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *toggle* your state; each time you find a `*` you *invert* the state of your function so that you can switch between uppercasing and lowercasing as you traverse the text.

You can most easily do this with `not`; `not a` would return `True` if it was `False` and vice-versa:

```
def trans(s):
    x = ""
    a = False
    for j in range(len(s)):
        if s[j] == "*":
            a = not a  # change state; false to true and true to false
            continue  # no need to add the star to the output
        if a:
            x += s[j].upper()
        else:
            x += s[j]
    return x
```

Each time you find a `*` character, `a` is toggled; by using `continue` at that time you also prevent the `*` character being added to the output, so the `replace()` can be avoided altogether. The `''.join()` call on a string produces just the same string again, it is not needed in this case.

You don't need a `range()` here, you could just loop over `s` directly. You could use better names too:

```
def trans(string):
    result = ""
    do_upper = False
    for character in string:
        if character == "*":
            do_upper = not do_upper  # change state; false to true and true to false
            continue  # no need to add the star to the output
        result += character.upper() if do_upper else character
    return result
```

Demo:

```
>>> def trans(string):
...     result = ""
...     do_upper = False
...     for character in string:
...         if character == "*":
...             do_upper = not do_upper  # change state; false to true and true to false
...             continue  # no need to add the star to the output
...         result += character.upper() if do_upper else character
...     return result
... 
>>> trans('S*t*a*r*s are every*where*')
'STaRs are everyWHERE'
```

Comment: To avoid relying on CPython optimization to get a linear behavior, you could use `result = []` and `result.append(..)` instead of `result = ""` and `result += ..`. And `return ''.join(result)` at the end.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** The other answers does a fine job of showing you how to fix your code. Here's another way to do it, which you may find easier once you learn regular expressions.

You could use `re.sub` function.

```
>>> s = "S*t*a*r*s are every*where*"
>>> re.sub(r'\*([^*]*)\*', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), s)
'STaRs are everyWHERE'
```

In regex `*` is a special meta character which repeats the previous token zero or more times. In-order to match a literal `*`, you need to use `\*` in the regex.

So `\*([^*]*)\*` regex matches every pair of `*` blocks ie (`*t*`, `*r*`, `*where*`) and the in-between characters (*chars present inside the `*` block*) are captured by the group 1.

For every match, `re.sub` function would replace the matched `*..*` block with `string-inside-*.upper()` . ie, it would apply the `upper()` function on the strings present inside the `*` and return the result as replacement string.

Comment: Not everything requires a regular expression. This doesn't explain where the OP went wrong either.

Comment: Tnx, but i just started with regular expersions so I'm not good with them

Comment: Alternatives are fine, but you are not really answering the question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: As I'm sure you know, laziness is a programmer virtue. :) I didn't down-vote, but I agree that regex should be avoided if a simple non-regex solution can be found, partly because regexes tend to impede readability, and partly because regex solutions aren't necessarily efficient. I guess these comments are **not** the place to discuss this issue, but feel free to bring it up in [sopython Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: @PM2Ring: why do you think implementing the FSM by hand is better than specifying a simple regular expression?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: In general, I think implementing a simple Finite State Machine by hand is better for the reasons I mentioned in my comment. And in this specific case, it seems fairly clear to me that Hybr1d is still learning the fundamentals of programming, so implementing a simple FSM like this is both a good exercise in using for loops, tests & flags, and a fairly painless intro to the concept of the FSM.

Comment: @PM2Ring: as I understand, your reasons are: (1) regexes impede readability compared to hand-written FSM (2) regex are slower than hand-written FSM (3) learn loop, conditionals, a simple FSM  instead of regexs. I agree with (3) (it can be considered a prerequisite to mastering regexes). I very much doubt (2) unless a profiler proves otherwise and about (1): once you've learned regexes, `\*([^*]*)\*` is shorter and more clear way to express the problem. Every programmer should learn regexes (it does not mean that they should be used everywhere: regexes are often (ab)used beyond their scope)

Answer (score 3):

Think of it like this. Whenever you see a `*`, you need to alternate between upper and original cases. So, implement the same in the code, like this

```
def trans(s):
    x, flag = "", False

    # You can iterate the string object with `for`
    for char in s:

        # The current character is a `*`
        if char == "*":
            # flip the flag everytime you see a `*`.
            flag = not flag
            # Skip further processing, as the current character is `*`
            continue

        if flag:
            # If the flag is Truthy, we need to uppercase the string
            x += char.upper()
        else:
            # Otherwise add the character as it is to the result.
            x += char

    # no need to `join` and `replace`, as we already skipped `*`. So just return.
    return x
```

Answer (score 3):

`a` should toggle between `True` and `False`. You only set it to `True`. Also iterate directly over the characters of the string instead over a index. And use more comprehensive variable names. The join is unnecessary and the replace is not needed, if you skip the '*' at once:

```
def trans(text):
    result = ""
    upper = False

    for char in text:
        if char == "*":
            upper = not upper
        elif upper:
            result += char.upper()
        else:
            result += char
    return result
```